# Symfony2 - Set label of ChoiceType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.7

I have a select field (choiceType) in a form which is automatically filled (with all the line in another table).

I would like to set the label (only the label, not the content of the select)...

I managed to do that for a textType with changing :

```
$builder->add('note')
```

to

```
$builder->add('note', 'text', array('label' => 'myNewLabel')
```

but I can't do that with a choiceType because if I change

```
$buidler->add('column')
```

to

```
$builder->add('column', 'choice', array('label' => 'myNewLabel')
```

the select isn't filled...

Comment: Is your column actually an entity ? 
Have you tried to change 'choice' by null ?

Comment: @henrily null did the job !! Thanks
(And Yes it was an entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is :

```
$builder->add('column', null, array('label' => 'myNewLabel')
```